# Photoshop CS6 Nvidia Optimus issue

Tags: windows-8, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus, photoshop-cs6

I am currently running Windows 8 on my computer.

When I open Photoshop using the integrated graphics card it works fine however when I use my Nvidia graphics card I am unable to view the tabbed window document. Only when I remove it from the tabbed view and drag it around with the cursor it becomes visible, otherwise I am unable to see the document.

[image: Document cannot be viewed.]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. In my case happens only when using the latest WHQL drivers from nvidia. Works fine with the previous beta version.

So there's two solutions

1. either download and use an older version of the driver until nvidia fixes the problem
2. or use Nvidia control panel to force photoshop use the integrated graphics processor which means you will lose some performance but photoshop will be workable again.

hope this helps until we get fixed drivers or some word from adobe about this issue.

Comment: alrighty then. I just used the nvidia control panel to force photoshop to use the integrated card :)

Answer (score 0):

Current solution: Set photoshop to use the discrete GPU only. This issue is no longer present on updated drivers.